# How to fix customer session time out in Magento 1.4.1.1?

Tags: customer-session

I'm looking for a way to limit customer log in session to 24 hours, but it seems not to be working at all.

I have done the following steps, none of them has changed a thing. After being logged in, customer stay logged in for ever...

```
System -> Configuration -> Services -> Magento Core Api ->General Settings
Client Session timeout (sec.): 86400

System -> Configuration->General > Web Session Cookie management
Cookie Lifetime: 86400
```

(Do I need to fill "cookie path" and "cookie domain" fields ?)
[image: Web Session Cookie Management screen]
     System -> Configuration-> Admin -> Security 
     Session_cookie_lifetime => 86400

```
/var/www/.htaccess
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
```

Do you have any idea about how I could manage it ?

Comment: Did you clear the browser cookies after setting those values? If not: If you had a non-expiring cookie before, it might still be there. Clear the cookies in your browser. And another thing: How/where do you store the sessions? File storage, DB, Redis,...? Please update your answer with some more information.

Comment: System -> Configuration->General > Web Session Cookie management is the right setting to do so. 
The Core Api setting and Admin Security setting have nothing to do with the customer login session.

Comment: I have cleared all cookies related to the website. Nothing happened. I have done this on Opera and Chrome. I don't know where the session is stored. Is there anyway I can find it ? In Web Session Cookie Management there are 2 fields that I don't know whether I need to fill them : "cookie path" and "cookie domain"

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't work for less thant 24h. It works now by setting the following to 86400 seconds...

System -> Configuration->General > Web Session Cookie

Comment: How about `Admin`  session time out in Magento 2.2?